# GRE - Probability Question

Tags: probability, gre-exam

For a certain probability experiment, the probability that event $A$ will occur is $\displaystyle\frac12$ and the probability that even $B$ will occur is $\displaystyle\frac13$. Which of the following values could be the probability that the event $A \cup B$ (that  is, the event $A$ or $B$, or both) will occur?

Indicate all such values.

A) $\displaystyle\frac13$
B) $\displaystyle\frac12$
C) $\displaystyle\frac34$

Answer is $B$ and $C$.
The probability that the event $A \cup B$ (that  is, the event $A$ or $B$, or both) will occur lies in the interval 1/2 to 5/6.
How? Please share how to determine the interval for the probability that the event $A \cup B$ (that  is, the event $A$ or $B$, or both) will occur.

Comment: The smallest it could be is when $B\subset A$. The largest it could be is when $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Can you find the probability for these extreme cases?

Comment: You were not told the relationship between A and B. So $P(A\cup B)$=P(A)+P(B)-$P(A\cap B)$

Comment: No @DavidMitra , I do not know how to find the probability for these extreme cases. Can you please share how to find?

Comment: If $B\subset A$, then $P(A\cup B)=P(A)=1/2$ (you could also just observe that the probability of the union is greater than both $P(A)$ and $P(B)$).  If $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then the probability of the union is the sum $P(A)+P(B)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$$

As David Mitra Said you have a sum and a negative term, naturally if $P(A \cap B)=0$  the expression is the largest possible and if $P(A \cap B)=P(A)$  or $P(A \cap B)=P(B)$ the expression is smallest (which is the case when $B \subset A$ or $A \subset B$).

Largest case $P(A \cap B)=0$:

$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)=P(A)+P(B)$$

Smallest case one $P(A \cap B)=P(A)$

$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)=P(B)$$

Smallest case two $P(A \cap B)=P(B)$

$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(B)=P(A)$$

I let you replace and see which one is the smallest.

Comment: Note that "smallest case one" cannot happen, because $\dfrac 1 2 = P(A) = P(A \cap B) \le P(B) = \dfrac 1 3$ is false.