# How to compute the probability of A union B when B is a subset of A?

Tags: probability, gre-exam

[GRE - Probability Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897234/gre-probability-question)

Regarding the case in the above problem where B is a subset of A:

Intuitively I see that the $P(A \cup B)= P(A)$ in this case. However when I compute the$ P(A \cup B)$ I get $1/3$. Where is my logic incorrect?

$P(A \cap B)$ = $P(B|A)\times P(A) = 1 \times 1/2$.

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = 1/3$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If $B\subseteq A$ then $A\cap B=B$, so  $$P(A\cap B)=P(B)=\frac{1}{3}.$$

In your calculation, you have used the wrong value of $P(B|A)$. You should have

$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B)}{P(A)}=\frac{1/3}{1/2}=\frac{2}{3}.$$