# probability question from GRE

Tags: probability

I am stuck on this question, even though the GRE book explained it.

**"For a certain probability experiment, the probability that event A will occur is 1/2 and the probability that event B will occur is 1/3 Which of the following values could be the probability that the event A ∪ B (that is, the event A or B, or both) will occur? Indicate all such values.
and 
the answers were 1/2 and 3/4**".

my issue with this question and the book guide explanation is the concept of "Large and small probability".

According to the guide " The probability of A ∪ B is least if B is a subset of A". But we don't know if B is a subset of A.

Comment: when you were pasting it the probabilities disappeared

Comment: Yes, your question is missing information. "... will occur is..." should continue.

Comment: My apologies!! i just edited it :)

Comment: I think this problem depends on the answer choices.

Comment: The answer to your question is found in the link:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897234/gre-probability-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is asking: If all you know is $P(A)=1/2$ and $P(B)=1/3$, then what are the largest and smallest possible values for $P(A\cup B)$? Without knowing what the answer choices are, the largest possible value occurs when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint (non-overlapping), in which case $P(A\cup B)=P(A) + P(B)=5/6$. The smallest possible value occurs when $B$ is a subset of $A$, in which case $P(A\cup B)=P(A)=1/2$. (These maximal and minimal relationships between events $A$ and $B$ are perhaps best seen by drawing a Venn diagram.)

Yes, we don't know for sure the relationship between $A$ and $B$, but logically it is impossible for $P(A\cup B)$ to be outside the range $1/2$ to $5/6$. The answer choices $1/2$ and $3/4$ fall inside the desired range; I'm guessing that the other possible answer choices are outside this range.

Comment: Great, but my issue is how did you interpret that the question is asking to find the "largest and smallest possible values for P(A∪B)P(A∪B)?" Because when I first read the question,  I deduced that I needed to find the probability of P(A∪B) only - which is P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B) and since we don't know about the relationship between A and B, (A ∩ B)=0-.

Comment: @Emma To determine which answer choices are possible, it's necessary to determine the largest and smallest possibilities for $P(A\cup B)$. Only then can you decide which choices "could be" and which are impossible.

Comment: .. and if we don't know the relationship between $A$ and $B$, it does not follow that $A\cap B$ is empty. That *could* be true, but other relationships are possible, including $B$ being a subset of $A$. (But $A$ being a subset of $B$ is not possible.)

Answer (score 0):

The question says "indicate **all** such values", and the two given values are $\dfrac12$ and $\dfrac34$.

You should be able to realize that both the given values are possible !

Answer (score 0):

The question asked, "Which of the following values *could* be the probability" (emphasis added by me).
It never asked what the probability *is*.
Hence you are only to decide which values are *possible* and which are not;
you are not to *find* a value.

What the guide is saying is that $P(A \cup B)$ cannot possibly
be *less* than it would be in the case where $B$ is a subset of $A$.
In that case $P(A \cup B) = \frac12$.
Of course you do not *know* that $B$ is a subset of $A$,
and therefore it is *possible* (but not certain) that 
$P(A \cup B)$ could be greater than $\frac12$.

You certainly cannot conclude that since you don't know the
relationship between $A$ and $B$, that therefore 
$A \cap B = \emptyset$.
You *do* know, because $P(B) < P(A)$, that $A \cap B \neq A$.
But it is consistent with the question's conditions that
$A \cap B  = B$, in which case you would have
$P(A \cup B) = \frac12$,
and it is also consistent with the question's conditions that
$P(A \cap B) = \frac{1}{12}$, in which case  $P(A \cup B) = \frac34$,
therefore you should select both $\frac12$ and $\frac34$
as *possible* values of $P(A \cup B)$.
You should not select $\frac13$, because it is not possible for
$P(A \cup B)$ to be so small.

Comment: Thanks! I was really having problems figuring out the guide's explanation.